question on conditional laws
Let $\xi \in \mathbb{R}^d$ be a random vector following a multivariate Gaussian distribution $\xi \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\Sigma)$. Consider the following linear transformation :
\begin{align*}
    \xi_a = H_a\xi , \quad \xi_b = H_b\xi 
\end{align*}
$H_a$, $H_b$ $\in \mathbb{R}^{n \times d}$ are full row rank. Let $\gamma_b : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a measurable function of $\xi_b$. Suppose the conditional law of $\xi_b$ given $(\xi_a$, $\gamma_b(\xi_b))$ is same as the conditional law of $\xi_b$ given $\xi_a$. i.e.
\begin{align*}
    \mathcal{L}_{\xi_b|\xi_a,\gamma_b(\xi_b)}(\cdot) =\mathcal{L}_{\xi_b|\xi_a}(\cdot) \qquad \xi-a.s.
\end{align*}
where $\mathcal{L}_{X|Y}(\cdot)$ denotes the conditional law of $X$ given $Y$.
Does this imply that there exists a function $g$ such that $\gamma_b(\xi_b) = g(\xi_a)\hspace{2mm} \quad \xi-a.s.$? I feel like it should, but I am unable to prove it. It is certainly true when $\gamma_b$ is linear, and that's easy to show using conditional expectations of Gaussians. Any help would be appreciated.
